# T-SQL data cleaning - spare row if certain atrribute is NULL when tuple occurrs more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Table with sample data**:

```
UserID | DateID     | Code      | Type
0815     20191211    'oef'       xx     -> keep that row in the result  
0815     20191211    'oef'       NULL   -> should not be in the result set because  
0916     20191212    'bin'       NULL   -> keep that row in the result set if there is just one occurrence for this User at that day.
```

In the above sample the Type and the Code can be NULL.
A conditional data clean up should be applied if the Type is NULL.
The second row should not be in the result-set because the only difference to the first is the Type which is NULL.
The third row exists only once for that User at that day and with that code, so it should be kept.

I can't imagine an elegant and performant solution for that clean up task. So if anybody has an idea I would be glad.

There is clustered Index on UserID and DateID (I could change it to a columnstore if it helps - MS SQL Server 2016).
We are talking about 100.000.000 rows in that table.

Comment: The first record of 0815 should be kept ?

Comment: Yes, the first row should be kept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all rows where the values in the two columns are not `NULL`.

Then you want `NULL` values is there is no corresponding row based on the *other* column.  Based on what I interpret as what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.code is not null and t.type is not null) or
      (t.code is null and
       not exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where t2.user = t.user and t2.dateid = t.dateid and
                         t2.code is not null and
                         (t2.type = t.type or t2.type is null and t.type is null)
                  )
      ) or
      (t.type is null and
       not exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where t2.user = t.user and t2.dateid = t.dateid and
                         t2.type is not null and
                         (t2.code = t.code or t2.code is null and t.code is null)
                  )
      ) ;
```

Comment: It does the job. I will see how it works with the amount of data. Thx

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9afb6/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTab (UserID int, DateID int , Code varchar(255),Type varchar(255))
INSERT INTO MyTab (UserID,DateID,Code,Type) VALUES (0815, 20191211 ,'oef','xx'),(0815, 20191211 ,'oef',NULL),(0916,20191212 ,'bin',NULL)
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY UserID desc) AS rn
    FROM MyTab )

    SELECT UserID,DateID,Code,Type FROM CTE
   where  Type IS  NULL and rn=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9afb6/2/0)**:

```
| UserID |   DateID | Code |   Type |
|--------|----------|------|--------|
|    916 | 20191212 |  bin | (null) |
```